# Google Maps - How to get a blank basemap

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to have a blank google map, without any basemap showing roadmap, terrain, hybrid or satellite data: just a white background to display my layer only.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're most probably interested in custom map types, you can reference Google Maps documentation for that here :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en#CustomMapTypes

Answer (score 4):

hexblot was correct with his suggestion to look at custom map types documentation. Here is what I did to have a blank map (white background) without any control.

```
function initialize(){
    var styles = [{
            stylers:[{ color: "#ffffff" }]
        }
    ];
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles);
    var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: centerlatlng,
        disableDefaultUI : true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: ['map_style']
        },
        mapTypeId: 'map_style'
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
}
```