# How to draw road base on lat lon

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps, dictionary

i have a list of lat lon, this is location collection of a road and i want to draw it on canvas,

i have try some solution from here

[https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/626899/Converting-Latitude-And-Longitude-to-an-X-Y-Coordi][1]

but i still can not draw the road
 This is lat lon list:

```
[35.6350019, 139.761, 35.634935, 139.761, 35.6343889, 139.7610111, 35.6341389, 139.761, 35.6339167, 139.7609544, 35.6336758, 139.7608861, 35.6335278, 139.7608294, 35.6334167, 139.76075, 35.6332592, 139.7606136, 35.6331667, 139.7605111, 35.6330647, 139.7603636, 35.6329722, 139.7601817, 35.6329072, 139.76, 35.6328703, 139.7598408, 35.6328333, 139.759625, 35.6328333, 139.7594544, 35.6328425, 139.7592839, 35.6328517, 139.7591475, 35.6328889, 139.7590111, 35.6329536, 139.7588294, 35.6330369, 139.7586817, 35.6331389, 139.7585111, 35.6332314, 139.7583975, 35.6333333, 139.7582839, 35.6334167, 139.7582158, 35.6335461, 139.7581361, 35.6336203, 139.7580908, 35.6337406, 139.7580453, 35.6338611, 139.7580111, 35.634, 139.7579886, 35.6341111, 139.7579886, 35.6342314, 139.758, 35.6343517, 139.7580339, 35.6344814, 139.7580908, 35.6345925, 139.7581475, 35.6347036, 139.7582158, 35.6348056, 139.7583067, 35.6349072, 139.7584203, 35.6349906, 139.7585453, 35.6350739, 139.7586817, 35.6351389, 139.7588181, 35.6352128, 139.7590453, 35.6352406, 139.7591817, 35.6352683, 139.7593522, 35.6352778, 139.7595225, 35.6352778, 139.7597044, 35.6352592, 139.7598522, 35.6352314, 139.7600225, 35.6351758, 139.7602725, 35.6350278, 139.7608975, 35.6350019, 139.761]
```

Answer (score 1):

You must draw a polyline and place it on the map.

check [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple).

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  // This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of William
  // Kingsford Smith's first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and
  // Brisbane, Australia.

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
      mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    });

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
      {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
      {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
      {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

This is hardcoded, which is usually not a practical solution.  Therefore, I would recommend writing some php code to populate the lat/lon point list from a MySQL db.

NOTE: you can also change the basemap to a custom basemap.  In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15077126/1166727), you will find code to display a white base, with no controls (note, you will not have continents, ocean, rivers, lakes, etc - just a white background).

Comment: thanks for your support, i want draw it on a clear flat, this is draw on googlemap only

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "clear flat".  Do you mean to say that you do NOT want a google basemap underneath your road?  I edited the answer to point to a way to change the basemap to a white canvas.

Comment: in case you mean that you want to draw a line on a blank page WITHOUT using google maps or OSM, please inform.  I just so happen to have developed a simple JS solution for that.

Comment: When you draw a polyline on a google map you will see the shape of that road, I mean I want to draw the shape of the road on the canvas without using the google map.

Comment: @LãoTà do you want to run this online or do you want an app to do it?  You must be more specific, otherwise your question will be shut down.  It has already been `put on hold`